# Problem to understand a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

In Norris, Markov chains, I found the following:

> > [...] a recurrence relation of the form
> >     $$
> > ax_{n+1}+bx_n+cx_{n-1}=0
> > $$
> >     where $a$ and $c$ were both non-zero. Let us try a solution of the form $x_n=\lambda^n$; then $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$. Denote by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the roots of this quadratic. Then
> >     $$
> > y_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n
> > $$
> >     is a solution.

Up to here everything is clear to me.

But I do not understand the following:

> > If $\alpha\neq\beta$ then we can solve the equations
> >     $$
> > x_0=A+B,~~~~~x_1=A\alpha+B\beta
> > $$
> >     such that $y_0=x_0$ and $y_1=x_1$; but
> >     $$
> > a(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})+b(y_n-x_n)+c(y_{n-1}-x_{n-1})=0
> > $$
> >     for all $n$, so by induction $y_n=x_n$ for all $n$.

Could you please explain me this passage?

Comment: It just shows that as $x_0=y_0$ and $x_1=y_1$, then by recurrence $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: But why is $x_0=y_0$ and $x_1=y_1$?

Comment: Because the equations were solved for $A$ and$B$ so that it is precisely the case. (Think that $y_0=A+B$ and $y_1=A\alpha+B\beta$.)

Comment: Could you please explain that? I think about that very long but do not understand this. ;(

Comment: Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in step $1$, you define $$y_n = A \alpha^n + B \beta ^n$$ and you "notice" that for any values of $A,B$, you know that $y_n$ will satisfy the reccurence equation.

In the second part, you set $A$ and $B$ to such values that $y_0=x_0$ and $y_1=x_1$. That is, you set $A$ and $B$ to satisfy the equations $A+B=x_0$ and $A\alpha + B\beta = x_1$, meaning that $$y_0 = A\alpha^0 + B\beta^0 = A + B = x_0$$ and $$y_1=A\alpha^1 + B\beta^1 = A\alpha + B\beta = x_1$$

As a result you know that $y_n$ is a sequence that satisfies:

$$y_0=x_0\\
y_1=x_1\\
\forall n\in\mathbb N: ay_{n+1} + by_n + cy_{n-1} = 0$$

and using these three equations, you can prove that $x_n=y_n$ for all values of $n$, meaning that the solution to the reccurence relation is $x_n = A\alpha^n + B\beta^n$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of your polynomial ($a\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c$) and $A, B$ are such that $A+B=x_0$ and $A\alpha + B\beta = x_1$.

Comment: Great, thank you. And how can I prove that $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: @mathfemi By induction. It is already true for $n=0,1$. For $n>1$, use the reccurence relation in the inductive step.

Comment: You mean I have to show by induction that $a(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})+b(y_n-x_n)+c(y_{n-1}-x_{n-1})=0$?

Comment: @mathfemi No, you have to show by induction that $y_n = x_n$.

Comment: Ok the induction is very short: Suppose it is shown for $n$, now do the inductive step $n\mapsto n+1$, then $ay_{n+1}=-by_n-cy_{n-1}=-bx_n-cx_{n-1}=ax_{n+1}$ so $y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}$. Thats it.

Comment: But I do not understand why $a(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})+b(y_n-x_n)+c(y_{n-1}-x_{n-1})=0$ for all $n$ and for what I need this. Because this only holds if $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$ but this is to show.

Comment: I think I do not need this at all.

Comment: @mathfemi The way you proved it, you really don't need it. What the textbook did was prove that $x_n - y_n = 0$ for all $n$ by proving that $x_0-y_0 = 0$ and $x_1-y_1$ and then using induction to prove that $x_{n+1} - y_{n+1} = 0$. But your method is just as valid.

Answer (score 1):

The unknown sequence is such that
$$ax_{n+1}+bx_n+cx_{n-1}=0.$$

We found a general sequence (with two free parameters $A$ and $B$),  $y_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ that is a solution this recurrence. Indeed, after simplification,
$$ay_{n+1}+by_n+cy_{n-1}=a(A\alpha^{n+1}+B\beta^{n+1})+b(A\alpha^n+B\beta^n)+c(A\alpha^{n-1}+B\beta^{n-1})=(a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c)A\alpha^{n-1}+(a\beta^2+b\beta+c)B\beta^{n-1}=0.$$
Now, if we choose $A$ and $B$ in such a way that $y_0=x_0$ and $y_1=x_1$, by recurrence this will extend to $y_n=x_n$, because the differences $y_n-x_n$ also verify the recurrence and are identically $0$:

$$a(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})+b(y_{n}-x_{n})+c(y_{n-1}-x_{n-1})=0,$$
with
$$y_0-x_0=0\text{ and }x_1-y_1=0.$$

Comment: Why is $a(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})+b(y_n-x_n)+c(y_{n-1}-x_{n-1})=0$ for all n and why does from this follow by induction that $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: By subtraction of the two recurrences in $x$ and $y$, and because $y_n-x_n=0$.

Comment: But that $x_n=y_n$ is to show...